# Curl authentication

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, bash, terminal

I am trying to download a file with cURL from a password protected directory on my site. It is not working. Instead of the downloading the requested file, it downloads a HTML file that says, "**Authentication Required!**" I'm not sure what the problem is.

I've tried both of these (with the same result). The username and password are correct (and if the link below is used in a web browser, the file downloads successfully).

1) The username and password are included as part of the URL.

```
curl https://username:wordpass.1@www.example.com/auth/file.dmg --O /file.dmg;
```

2) The username and password are included as an option.

```
curl -u username:wordpass.1 https://www.example.com/auth/file.dmg --O /file.dmg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that authentication was set to `Digest` for the realm. Changing it to `Basic` fixed the problem.

Comment: Note that `--digest` or `--anyauth` should have done the trick for you as well since curl doesn't bother to detect what kind of authentication the server wants unless you tell it to with `--anyauth`.